# PHP recursive query based on sql select

Tags: php, recursive-query

I have 2 tables in a MariaDB

Table 1 structure:

ID (primary auto-increment) itemType(ENUM) and itemName(varchar)

The ENUM has 4 possibilities - "heading","section","text","citation".

Table 2 structure

ID (primary auto-increment) TID(int) parentID(int) and childID(int)

though it's possible I may need another column to perform the recursion.

Table 1 contains the text, and Table 2 the relationships of the text to each other.

The purpose of the query is to produce a nested JSON array/object in a tree structure.

example:`[{itemType:"heading",sub[{itemType:"section",sub:[{itemType:"text"},{itemType:"text"},{itemType:"text"},{itemType:"text"}]},{itemType:"section",sub:[{itemType:"text"},{itemType:"text"}]} ]}]`

so it can produce an HTML tree such as

- Heading 1

  - Section 1

    - Text 1
    - Text 2
    - Text 3
    - Text 4
  - Section 2

    - Text 2
    - Text 4
- Heading 2

  - Section 2

    - Text 1
    - Text 3
  - Section 3

    - Text 2
    - Text 4
    - Text 5
    - Text 6

Problems
A heading can only exist once in the list
Sections and text can appear many times in the whole list but only once within each heading
Sections can be a child of any header so it's not "tied"
Text can be a child of any section so it's not "tied"

So I start with

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemType = 'header' ")->fetchAll();
```

The loop through $data

```
foreach( $data as $row ){writeMessage( $row['ID'],$row['ID']);}
```

Where writeMessage() is my recursive function

```
 function writeMessage($ID, $TID){
        global $pdo;    
        $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM testing LEFT JOIN items ON items.ID = '$ID' WHERE parentID = '$ID' AND TID = '$TID' ");
         while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            echo  $row['ID'].' '.$row['itemName'].' '.$row['childID'].'<br/>';
            writeMessage($row['childID'],$TID);
         }
     }
```

But I never get the right results.

Help and suggestions please, it's along time since I used PHP in this way

Comment: Stop using globals. Start [**using Prepared Statements for your PDO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection?rq=1)